# How do I create product and product display once, like in Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: 7, commerce

In Kickstart you just go Add Product and it creates both, the Product for admin area product list and the Product Display. How do I do that in regular Drupal install with regular Commerce module? Because now I have to go each time to create the actual product for admin product list and then go create a product display for users. Isn't that a bit annoying?

I cannot use Kickstart, it's too late already and it's too big and overcrowded with too much of not needed features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is through the contributed module [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).